# Developing assistive application for macOS, apiDisabled

Tags: swift, xcode, macos

I am trying to use the Accessibility API using Swift, but am getting a consistent [apiDisabled](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/applicationservices/axerror/kaxerrorapidisabled?language=objc) error.

When I go into the System Prefs to disable/enable my app in the Privacy > Accessibility section, I get a "success" result, but once I change the code, it goes back to the error.

Mind you this is a hodge-podge of references based on reading up on this functionality and APIs, I just can't seem to get over this `apiDisabled` error. Here's my code:

```swift
func getWindow() {
    let appBundleIdentifier = "com.AppIdentifier"
    let myApp: NSRunningApplication? = NSRunningApplication
        .runningApplications(withBundleIdentifier: appBundleIdentifier).last as NSRunningApplication?

    if let pid = myApp?.processIdentifier {

        let axuiApp = AXUIElementCreateApplication(pid)

        // List the windows.
        var value: AnyObject?
        let result: AXError = AXUIElementCopyAttributeValue(axuiApp, kAXWindowsAttribute as CFString, &value)

        print(result)

    }
}
```

I'm expecting at least the `apiDisabled` error to go away so I can start digging into how to access the data I need.

Answer (score 0):

Try manually adding your application to the `Accessibility` section.

If you use the automated discovery for the Accessibility apps (and not the `+` button) it might detect a new app every time you build the app as it is not signed.

Comment: Thanks Shahar! Yeah, that's what I've been doing – the app doesn't bring up the system dialog for updating the Security/Privacy settings, so I found the app via Finder and added it manually. Unfortunately it still shows the `apiDisabled` error.

Comment: after you added it manually (`+` and then dragging the app) - once you rebuild or build the app again - does it appear again or disappear from the list? if it stay - is there a checkmark or not?

Comment: After I add it manually, and then rebuild, it's still listed in the Sys Prefs, and there's a checkmark there.

Comment: And you are still getting an error? can you share your code (or an example of it - even via github)? It sounds like an issue I'll have to actually check on my mac ...

Comment: Here's the code -- thanks so much for offering to look at it. https://github.com/ctruelson/SwiftTests

Comment: please make sure the project works. `thingsBundleIdentifier` was wrong (easy fix), missing `sayButtonClicked` and there's a warning of `Unknown Window class _TtC10HelloWorld14CmdSpaceWindow in Interface Builder file, creating generic Window instead` not a good place to start...

Comment: Sorry about that Shahar. I made some changes and force pushed so you might want to delete the directory and re-clone the repo. Thanks again for looking.

Comment: I'm trying to understand what you are trying to do ... in the example you are trying to take control of the Finder App? The actual 1st application was better, as you were trying to get a hold of your own button ... What's the required result? Finder app or your app?